# Samsung Galaxy S2 Root

Tags: root, galaxy

I tried rooting my S2 but something obviously went wrong. When i was finished rooting and tried rebooting it, it was just stuck on the bootscreen with the yellow triangle. I went to sleep and the next day it was still like that, so I went on the internet to find some help. I found the stock rom and kernel and tried booting that. Now what happens is that the boot screen comes and after 10 seconds the phone just turns off. When i tried unrooting it, i couldnt because Odin wont recognice my phone. I have also tried using Heimdall, but that wont find my phone either.

I have the international version, think it's called something like I900 etc.

I tried asking on Reddit and when they couldnt help me, they sent me here. I also discovered that i forgot to put the phone in debugging mode.

I can still acces the download and recovery mode, and yesterday i ordered a USB jig, that will be coming in the mail soon.

What should i do?

Comment: Sorry, but the Redditors gave bad advice.

Comment: This is a platform for programmers and not for hacking your phone.

Comment: I don't need to hack it, i just need to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you flash a wrong kernel/Image. Try to get a Orginal Kernel and a Orginal Rom.
Together with the correct PIT File.

Be sure to check if you have a 9100 or a 9100G .. this is different processor.

If you get into the Download Mode... all can be fixed.
If you get an Screen with 3 Symbols (Phone, Triangle, PC)
You are in the First Stage Bootloader, and must repartition Flash.
Odin should always detect your Phone.

Please search for Recovery Flash, or unbrick in some Android-Forums...
I don't want to link  because there were many good sites.

Hope this helps.

PS: Flashing isn't automatically Illegal.

I'm Software-Developer and need sometimes to root Smart-phones, with custom kernels for different Projects.

Answer (score 0):

For rooting There are 2 apps which will help you to have superuser permission on your device-one is [superuser](http://www.apkdaddy.com/2013/07/chainsdd-superuser-elite-apk-v313-free.html) and the other one is 
I recommend supersu over superuser.
Supersu also has an option to install via clockworkmod recovery([can be installed via rom manager](http://www.apkdaddy.com/2013/06/rom-manager-apk-premium-free.html)) So it becomes an system app.